# Did everything Christ did perfectly match what was required for salvation?

Tags: life-of-jesus, christology, messiah, atonement

I was thinking about Christ's suffering for sinners and am wondering, 'Since everything he did as a man on earth was a form of suffering for the eternal son, did everything he do perfectly match what was required for salvation?' Did his grasp for food and his sleep as a child, required for our salvation? Was everything perfectly matched with what was required, or were some things neutral, or not required?

Answer (score 3):

Interesting.

Yes.

Salvation required the sacrifice of a perfect and immaculate victim. This means that it was required of Christ to do everything in accordance with God's will. There is of course no question that He could and did carry out this obligation. He was perfectly obedient. If He was not, He could not serve as an appropriate sacrifice. But then, if He was not perfectly obedient, He wouldn't be Jesus, either.

Does this include all of his intentional actions? Yes. This is because all actions can be done *for God* ([related](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/14753/3941)). Here is one reference, dealing with the use of material things: "There is scarcely any proper use of material things which cannot be thus directed toward the sanctification of men and the praise of God" (from the [Catechism](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c4a1.htm) section 1670). And here is another, from [1 Corinthians 10](http://www.usccb.org/bible/1corinthians/10/31):

> 31 So whether you eat or drink, or whatever you do, do everything for the glory of God.

We can be sure that Jesus did do everything, **absolutely** everything, for the glory of God; and doing so **was required** for salvation, because salvation required the sacrifice of a perfect and immaculate victim.