# According to Christians who will go to hell?

Tags: life-of-jesus, heaven, hell

According to Christians:

> Jesus died and rose again to save the world from all their sins.

Based on this, do all people go to heaven and no one go to hell? If not who will go to hell?

Comment: Which Christians? The answer here could be "none" or "very many indeed". This site is about asking specific, focused questions about particular doctrinal traditions, because it just can't work if everyone is putting their own personal opinion in. It might help if you read [What makes a good focused question?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/690/what-makes-a-good-focused-question)

Comment: There are basically two answers: everyone will go to heaven, or only some people will go to heaven. I suggest you ask what the Biblical basis is for one of those positions, because otherwise this will get closed as being too opinion based.

Comment: For Jehovah's Witnesses, there is no hell. The wicked will be annihilated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a category error.  See [Is it valid to ask if “Christianity” teaches anything?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/is-it-valid-to-ask-if-christianity-teaches-anything)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Only those who reject Christ.**

> "For God so loved the world that He gave His only begotten Son that
>   whosoever believeth in Him should not perish but have everlasting
>   life." John 3:16

God doesn't send anyone to hell. A person goes to hell because they reject the Savior.

The Old testament saints were sanctified by faith in the future savior. They believed in the same concept Christians believe except they were looking ahead to the cross. They believed that the savior -would- come.

> "God will provide the sacrifice." Abraham to Issac in Genesis.

We are redeemed by the belief in the same savior except that we believe that the savior has came, looking -back- to Cross.

The cross is the Epicenter of all time. Everything before and everything after in scripture and in faith either moves towards or returns to that moment. The moment the giver of life died to save the people He loved so dear.

**-Expansion-**

I was asked to expand upon the notion of why only those who reject Christ are those who go to hell. I will do so here because I don't want to interfere with my already user accepted response.

**Why do we need the Savior and who is He?**

In order to understand why rejecting Christ send us to hell we must understand why we need Christ in the first place. From the beginning God in His Holy and Righteous state declared for any an every sin atonement must be made. A blood sacrifice must be given. In the book of Genesis Chapter 3 after man falls God declares that because of Adam's sin he will return to the dust he was formed from. He also makes them clothes using skin which implies death being required. Then in one the books of God's law, Leviticus, we see full details concerning offerings made to God to atone for sin. Start at Chapter 1 and just keep reading. Point is according to God blood must be spilt in order to reconcile man back to the Holy God and not just any blood but, the innocent blood of a spotless lamb. No amount of praying could make atonement. Works could not make atonement. Nothing but faith in that blood sacrifice as an offering to cover sin. **But** there is a problem with this system. It has to be repeated. Over and over throughout history the "Passover" ritual was done in honor of that fateful night that God spared the Hebrew from death in Egypt. Just as He said then He says now.

> "...when I see the blood, I will pass over you, and the plague shall
>   not be upon you to destroy you..." Exodus 12:13

So Why then do we need the savior? Because the sacrifices could never atone for all the sin of humanity. They were a temporary solution until God's plan was completed circling back to my statement about Abraham "God will provide a sacrifice." He did that very thing in the precious blood of Jesus Christ our savior and our Lord. He being the divine Word of God in the flesh (John 1) stepped into His own creation forsook Glory to become the lowest of men and to provide the atonement for our sins with his shed blood upon the cross. Fulfilling ever prophetic word concerning the messiah. Living a perfect and spotless life free of sin. Seeing as He is and was the only hope man could have of ever doing so being conceived of the Holy Spirit.

**Why is rejecting Him the only way to hell?**

> "23 For the wages of sin is death, but the gift of God is eternal life
>   in Christ Jesus our Lord." -Romans 6:23

If we understand what the apostle Paul is saying here we know two things.

1. God demands atonement. (refer to section above)
2. God provided atonement as a free gift of grace in and through Christ.

Now knowing that salvation is a gift of grace that God himself provided we see ourselves free from our sins, our punishment for them being paid by Christ, and are now freely able to come to the throne of God. John 3:16 says "For God so loved **the World**, that he gave his only Son..." meaning everyone. It doesn't matter if your white, black, red, blue, yellow, green, or orange. You have just as much gift of salvation as anyone else. All it boils down to is this. Do you believe it? God gave the gift of salvation you can receive it...or you can reject it and try to get by on your own. Prayer won't atone for sin. Works won't atone for sin. Living a good life won't atone for sin. There's no other way except in Christ.

> "I am THE way, THE Truth and THE life, no one can come unto the Father
>   except by me."
>
> "I am the door."
>
> "I am the living water."
>
> "I am the bread of life."

and my favorite...

> "I am the resurrection and the life. He that believes in me though he
>   die, yet shall he live." -Jesus

Hope this helps, enlightens or just brings a smile of confidence to somebody today. God bless.

Comment: Does this include all the people who have never heard of Jesus? Or they had no chance to reject or accept?

Comment: Greg, I answered that on the question you posted a while back. I think. If not or if you wish to discuss our views I wouldn't mind. Thanks.

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak there are other questions that answer that.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by 'only those who reject Christ'? Specifically the word 'reject'. This is the crux of your answer and you leave it hanging in the air while the rest has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @gideonmarx Would you prefer I edit my answer or comment on the matter?

Comment: It should form part of your answer and then tie it in with the rest. Even though the question is on hold it might be worth doing if you have time. I will be interested to see how you do it in any case.

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak You'll find this interesting http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/does-my-monk-go-to-heaven

Comment: Tyler is there a way to discuss it in chat? Can you give me a link and I will join?

Comment: I also agree with gideon marx, I have heard people respond many times: 1) people who never heard about Jesus had some "basic" understanding of right and wrong from nature, 2) those who reject Jesus are basically choose not to go to heaven. While 1 is true, they don't mention the whole "rejecting" thing in that case. They just skip over it. And as for the second, doesn't rejecting involve actually being faced with a fully informed choice? If I told you "believe in Temujin!" and you didn't have more evidence, what are you "rejecting"? Certainly you didn't mean to say no about going to Heaven!

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak I don't really know how to open a chat room but you are welcome to email me. My email is on my profile page.

Answer (score -1):

Anyone can go to heaven and God doesn't want anyone to go to hell.  However, some people reject Jesus.  He still died for them, but they don't care.  I heard something once that was very helpful for me.  It was something like, "God loves you so much that when you die, He will give you what you loved most while you were alive forever.  If you love Him the most, you will be with him forever.  (That is called heaven.)  If you loved anything else more, you will get it forever, but you will also see how much you are missing without God.  If you loved anything besides God the most, having it forever will be hell."

Comment: What about all the people who lived in North America, China etc. in the year 40 AD? They never were presented with the gospel. Don't you have to be aware of something in order to reject it? So do they all go to heaven?

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak Good point.  The best thing I can say is natural law says that there is an all powerful being (God).  Even if they never heard about God, they still know natural law.  People who have never heard about God still know what is right and wrong.

Comment: There is a sense that God's judgement will give people what they want, but the Bible more often says that judgement comes from God's wrath.

Comment: @curiousdannii  I would say that when something bad happens because of sin, it is not God's wrath.  "The wages of sin is death."  If someone commits adultery and then gets AIDs, I would say it is not God's wrath, it is simply the nature of sin to have bad effects.

Comment: But Romans 1 says that God shows his anger by letting us experience the consequences of our sin.

Comment: @curiousdannii  Yes, but God still loves us.  I would say God is never angry at **us**.  He is angry at our sins, so He lets is experience their consequences in hope that we will never do them again.

Answer (score -1):

Christianity, as defined by this forum, covers many differing views.  From an evangelical perspective, we are all guilty of sin against God--rebellion against His authority.  Simply put, we are guilty of high treason--not merely minor infractions.

Our good works can never outweigh our bad.  I don't know where that idea comes from, but we certainly do not operate that way in relation to our government.  No amount of good works would make up for committing murder or rape or even speeding.  There is a penalty for every crime that must be paid.

> For by works of the law no human being will be justified in his sight, since through the law comes knowledge of sin.  Romans 3:20 ESV

The same is true with our relationship to God.  We have committed high treason by rejecting His authority in our lives every time we sin.  No one is worthy, and everyone is guilty.  Justice can only be served when the penalty is paid.  We are completely unable to pay the penalty of our sins by our good deeds.  We are utterly helpless and hopeless by ourselves.

However, God loves us and desires to not merely overlook our sins, but to fully pay for them.  He is certainly able to do so.  The Eternal Son ([see the trinity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/72/biblical-basis-for-the-doctrine-of-the-trinity)) entered into His creation and took on the name Jesus, which means "God saves", because God became a Man to save us from our sins.  He died as payment for our sins, thereby satisfying the requirements of His own justice.  Our penalty is, then, fully paid.

It is then left to us whether or not we accept this gift.  We can refuse this payment and believe we are good enough on our own.  In that case, we will pay for it ourselves, spending eternity in the place where God is not--what we call hell.

> For Christ also suffered once for sins, the righteous for the unrighteous, that he might bring us to God, being put to death in the flesh but made alive in the spirit.  1 Peter 3:18 ESV

If, however, we do accept His payment for us, made on our behalf, and trust His work rather than our own, then He makes us His own children and forgives us completely.

So, in conclusion, all are completely unrighteous and unworthy.  However, those who admit that and accept God's payment for the penalty of their sins will be forgiven and spend eternity with God.  Those who reject this payment will spend eternity in the place where God is not.

> Whoever believes in the Son has eternal life; whoever does not obey the Son shall not see life, but the wrath of God remains on him.  John 3:36 ESV

Comment: How does one believe in the Son and obey the Son? Do JWs believe in the Son and obey him? I am confused because people who accept Jesus but don't believe he is God are said by evangelicals to have refused Jesus, but they accepted his gift so I don't get it.

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak that's a decent question, but it doesn't belong here. You should ask it as a new question.

Comment: Please clarify your answer for me because the way I understand it sounds demented. Are you saying that God insists that every human pay a price for the sin of 'high treason' against His authority? That it is to be paid by Jesus on the cross or humans in hell? Please do not explain. A simple yes or no will do.

Comment: @gideonmarx I will not limit how you ask questions, and I will not be limited on how I answer them.  Either a person accepts the payment Jesus offered on their behalf OR that person is left to pay the penalty himself.  The penalty must be paid one way or another.

Comment: We might have a language problem here because I simply do not understand what you mean. Do you mean a penalty, or is it a punishment? Jesus was obviously not punished (or not as far as we know), so one could say he paid a penalty. Surely an eternity in hell is a 'punishment' that will never pay nor atone because it lasts an eternity. So maybe for humans you meant to use the word 'punishment'?