# What happens to those souls who have not been--nor ever will be--exposed to the teachings of the Bible?

Tags: life-of-jesus

My question relates to those who have only ever known one teaching which was derived from their birth religion, especially those who live secluded lives, far from society, and have their own spiritual beliefs.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Please see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) and also take the [tour] and see the [help] to help you learn how the site works. I hope to see you post again soon.

Comment: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/does-my-monk-go-to-heaven