# What are the implications of Jesus Christ being the only way to obtain eternal life?

Tags: eternal-life

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens to people who have never heard about Jesus?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/what-happens-to-people-who-have-never-heard-about-jesus)

In John 14:6 Jesus says "I am the Way the Truth and the Life: no man cometh unto the Father but by Me."

What are the implications of this statement with regards to those that have never heard of Christ? I'm thinking specifically of those who lived before he was born, and those who, even after his birth, never hear anything about him (for example people who live in tribes in the Amazon). Are these souls doomed to suffer in hell for eternity, and if so how is that just?

Also, how does the fate of these lost souls affect my fate as a Christian, given that Christ commanded us to spread the Gospel?

Comment: This is why it is vitally important that Christians do their job in preaching the gospel and making disciples of all nations everywhere.

Comment: Appreciated, but that doesn't answer my question regarding those that are never reached.

Comment: The above is a comment not an answer.

Comment: @hammar Agreed.

Comment: @hammer I searched for a similar question but clearly did not phrase it the same way, thank you.

Comment: I think the answers provided in the question that hammer pointed out are sufficient in my opinion, so I'll flag this to be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

1. All people have knowledge of God. [Romans 1:19-20](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%201:19-20&version=ESV)
2. All people reject God. [Romans 1:21](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%201:21&version=ESV)
3. All people are guilty before God. [Romans 1:24](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%201:24&version=ESV), [1:26](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%201:26&version=ESV), [1:29-31](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%201:29-31&version=ESV)
4. All people are condemned for rejecting God. [Romans 3:20](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%203:20&version=ESV)
5. God has made a way of salvation for the lost. [Romans 3:21-22](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%203:21-22&version=ESV)
6. People cannot come to God apart from faith in Christ. [Romans 5:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%205:1&version=ESV)
7. Christ commands the church to make the gospel known to all peoples. [Romans 10:13-15](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%2010:13-15&version=ESV)

Therefore,

(Rom 10:14-15 ESV)  14 How then will they call on him in whom they have not believed? And how are they to believe in him of whom they have never heard? And how are they to hear without someone preaching?  15 And how are they to preach unless they are sent? As it is written, “How beautiful are the feet of those who preach the good news!”